# Angular File Viewer Net core

Tags: angular, file, .net-core, middleware

I use an open source component by display files:

Angular component => https://angular-doc-viewer.firebaseapp.com/

If I upload a pdf from https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p5329.pdf on url input  and click go, the component displays the pdf correctly.

And then I created an api solutions with net core for serving my files and I have a controller that returns  a FileResult. Tests with Postman and images are displayed correctly, but pdf doesn't work because is on postman but neither on Angular viewer.

Then I activated browser directory files and I go to by url on chrome yes display pdf correctly but doesn't show in viewer by url.

I need a file middleware with auth for return files(pdf, docx) and display on file viewer.

[image: Controller returns fileResult]

[image: Directory configure]

[image: PDF Display from Directory]

[image: Directory]

[image: File from Directory]

Answer (score 0):

I Test on portal azure and works fine!